# Cannot sign into hotmail.co.uk account using Outlook 2007

Tags: outlook.com, microsoft-outlook

I'm not able to check my UK Hotmail emails through outlook 2007, but another Hotmail email works fine. I have downloaded Outlook Hotmail connector, but I still can't check the UK Hotmail emails.

Comment: Downloaded Outlook connector and still cannot check emails doesn't give us a clue of what could be wrong. Give us a screenshot or some error code

Comment: There is an attempted edit that looks like it may be yours.  If so, you can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  If you have created a second account, that will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As of May 2016 (perhaps earlier), Microsoft is moving all the Hotmail accounts to Outlook.com. In Outlook, use Outlook.com as the mail provider and enter your Hotmail login and password.